# stdint.h include_next'd from stdint.h not found

Tags: c, macos, gcc, 68000, stdint

I have been putting together a m68k cross compile "environment/toolchain" of sorts for some upcoming projects I have planned, and I'm having an issue when using it on macOS (my native environment) specifically.

If I follow my own instructions to install on Linux (https://github.com/tomstorey/m68k_bare_metal/blob/master/INSTALL-Debian-Ubuntu.md), then in my code I am able to use types such as `uint8_t` etc through `#include <stdint.h>`.

But if I install on macOS and attempt to do the same thing I am greeted with this error:

```
In file included from main.c:1:
/Users/tstorey/m68k/m68k-unknown-elf/lib/gcc/m68k-unknown-elf/9.3.0/include/stdint.h:9:16: fatal error: stdint.h: No such file or directory
    9 | # include_next <stdint.h>
      |                ^~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
make: *** [main.o] Error 1
```

I've done a little searching around, but I'm not having much luck finding an answer, perhaps because I don't really know what to search for other than "stdint.h not found".

One topic I did find suggested that `include_next` shouldnt really be used, but that same person wouldnt recommended modifying the original `stdint.h` file to work around it. Presumably since in that case it is including `<stdint.h>` then this file should be located somewhere "system wise", and `gcc` should know where to look to find it? But presumably that location doesnt exist.

In the same directory where the the `stdint.h` file I am trying to include is located there is a `stdint-gcc.h` file which, if I include this in my code, it will compile fine, no worries.

The original `stdint.h` file does seem to attempt to include this file, but only if `__STDC_HOSTED__` is not defined:

```
$ cat stdint.h
#ifndef _GCC_WRAP_STDINT_H
#if __STDC_HOSTED__
# if defined __cplusplus && __cplusplus >= 201103L
#  undef __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
#  define __STDC_LIMIT_MACROS
#  undef __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
#  define __STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS
# endif
# include_next <stdint.h>
#else
# include "stdint-gcc.h"
#endif
#define _GCC_WRAP_STDINT_H
#endif
```

Sorry if this post is a bit wofty, but I am not experienced enough with `gcc` etc to really be able to work this out and I'm still learning a lot about setting all of this up, so I'm wondering if anyone knows what I have missed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When your particular version of gcc has been built, it was apparently not built for a *hosted environment* (i.e. full availability of a standard C library, for example *newlib*). When this is the case, you cannot expect standard library support and are on your own.

You probably want to re-build gcc with *newlib* support.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, gcc does not come with std* header files, these come from some kind of flavour of c library?

Answer (score 0):

Quoting another mans reply

> For those building inside minimalists containers, the error caused by the # include_next <stdint.h> from /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/*/include/stdint.h which might be provided by libc6-dev (instead of avr-libc).

Installing `libc6-dev` should probably resolve the issue.

source: https://github.com/castwide/solargraph/issues/195#issuecomment-614064314